# Complex Trigonometry Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

How do you solve a complex trigonometry function using the identities of $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$?

$\tan(z)=2i$, $z$ is any complex number

Comment: How did you try? show your efforts.

Comment: For a complex argument $z$, $\tan z = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{i(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we have:

$$e^{xi}-e^{-xi}=\cos\left(x\right)+\sin\left(x\right)i-\left(\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)i\right)=2\sin\left(x\right)i\tag1$$

And:

$$e^{xi}+e^{-xi}=\cos\left(x\right)+\sin\left(x\right)i+\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)i=2\cos\left(x\right)\tag2$$

So:

$$\tan\left(x\right)=\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(x\right)}=\frac{\frac{e^{xi}-e^{-xi}}{2i}}{\frac{e^{xi}+e^{-xi}}{2}}=$$
$$\frac{e^{xi}-e^{-xi}}{2i}\cdot\frac{2}{e^{xi}+e^{-xi}}=\frac{e^{-xi}-e^{xi}}{e^{xi}+e^{-xi}}\cdot i\tag3$$

So, when $\text{n}\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\tan\left(x\right)=\text{n}i=\frac{e^{-xi}-e^{xi}}{e^{xi}+e^{-xi}}\cdot i\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{n}=\frac{e^{-xi}-e^{xi}}{e^{xi}+e^{-xi}}\tag4$$

Let $\text{u}:=e^{xi}$:

$$\text{n}=\frac{\frac{1}{\text{u}}-\text{u}}{\text{u}+\frac{1}{\text{u}}}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{u}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\text{n}}{1+\text{n}}}\tag5$$